# $ZF + AC_\omega$ prove the propositional compactness theorem for arbitrary languages

Tags: set-theory, propositional-calculus, model-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $ZF$ be the Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory and let $AC_\omega$ be the countable axiom of choice.

In $ZF+AC\omega$ one can prove the propositional compactness theorem for countable languages.

My question is: in $ZF+AC_\omega$ can I prove the propositional compactness theorem for arbitrary languages?

I suppose the answer is negative, so, if I assume $ZF+AC_\omega+$"propositional compactness theorem for arbitrary languages" can I obtain a contradiction?

Comment: The answer to both your questions (under the nontriviality assumption that $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent in the first place) is **no**: propositional compactness for arbitrary languages is **independent** of $\mathsf{ZF+AC_\omega}$, meaning that the latter neither proves nor disproves the former.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the first question is negative, even if you strengthen $AC_\omega$ to $DC$ (dependent choice). Solovay's model for "all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable" gives a counterexample, since there are no non-principal ultrafilters on $\omega$ in this model (and propositional compactness implies that all proper filters can be extended to ultrafilters). If you worry about the inaccessible needed for Solovay's model, then Shelah's model for "all sets of reals have the Baire property" works as well.

For the second question, note that the theory you asked about is included in ZFC, so it is consistent (provided of course that ZF is consistent).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So Solovay constructed a model of $ZF+DC+$"all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable" (I take it as a black box theorem). But I don't understand how to use this theorem to prove that the propositional compactness theorem fails in this model.

Comment: ZF + DC + "All sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable" proves that there are no nonprincipal ultrafilters on the set $\omega$ of natural numbers (essentially because such an ultrafilter would violate the zero-one law). But propositional compactness implies the existence of nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\omega$ (and indeed on all infinite sets).

Comment: More in details...how $ZF+DC+$"all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable" can prove that there are no nonprincipal ultrafilters on the set $\omega$?